# Import Excel xlsx to Python using Panda - Error Message - How to resolve?

Tags: excel, import, xlsx

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\royli\Downloads\Product List.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1' ) 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Product'])
print (df)
```

*****Error Message*****

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\royli\Downloads\Product List.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1' ) 
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 37, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\royli\\Downloads\\Product List.xlsx'
 
KeyboardInterrupt

```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I get that problem am gonna change \ symbols to \ \ symbols and generally its solved. Try it.

Comment: It says there is not any folder at your described path. Am gonna try to find new way to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Visual Studio Code.

```
table = pd.read_excel('Sales.xlsx')
```

When running the program on Pycharm, there were no errors.

When trying to run the same program in Visual Studio Code, it showed an error, without any changes.
To fix it, I had to address the file with //. Ex:

```
table = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\paste\\Desktop\\archives\\Sales.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Pycharm and after reviewing the Post and replies, I was able to get this resolved (thanks very much). I didn't need to specify a worksheet, as there is only one sheet on the Excel file I am reading.
I had to add the r (raw string), and I also removed the drive specification c:
`data = pd.read_excel(r'\folder\subfolder\filename.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in your code editor see if you can locate yourself with cd in the terminal part of the code editor. On a Mac you use ls to show the contents.  Go to the folder using cd, in my case was Desktop instead of C Drive. Then the code worked without any issues.